# Store static transaction details as JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb

My application generates payments to contractors based on a number of different objects on our platform. For example, we have jobs and line items per job. Each of those have their own details.

After we pay out a contractor, sometimes job details are changed around, for whatever reason, so sometimes we'll have a generated (email) receipt that says one thing but the job details queried from the database say something else.

I've been thinking about saving the current job details as JSON as storing it in a text field for each payment, so that we have a "snapshot" of the object at the time it was paid.

a) Does something like that make sense to do? Or would it be better to lock old jobs so they aren't editable anymore?

b) If it does make sense, would it be worth it/useful to store it in something like MongoDB? Would it be less complicated to just keep it all in mysql?